# Missing OpenMP 4 function in GCC 4.8.2

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, openmp

Compiling the following code:

```
#include <iostream>                                                             
#include <omp.h>                                                                

int main(int argc, char *argv[])                                                
{                                                                               
  std::cout << omp_get_default_device() << '\n';                                
  return 0;                                                                     
}
```

with GNU G++ 4.8.2, using the command:

```
g++ -fopenmp test.cpp
```

results in the following error message:

```
test.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
test.cpp:6:39: error: ‘omp_get_default_device’ was not declared in this scope
std::cout << omp_get_default_device() << '\n';
```

Am I right to think that `omp_get_default_device` should be callable outside of a parallel region? Is this a bug?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`omp_get_default_device` appears to have been added in [OpenMP 4.0](http://www.openmp.org/mp-documents/OpenMP4.0.0.pdf) ([here](http://www.openmp.org/mp-documents/OpenMP3.1.pdf) is the 3.1 spec which does not have that function). GCC 4.8 only supports version 3.1, though 4.0 will be supported in GCC 4.9: http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/openmp

Comment: Thanks. I mistakenly associated the GCC 4.8.2 announcement at gcc.gnu.org, with the OpenMP 4 news which follows.